# PostgreSQL pg_basebackup tar file does not yield pg_xlog upon unpacking

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.5

I configured a basebackup on a Postgres 9.5 server, specifying that the xlogs should be fetched, and that the file will be a compressed tar archive.  I configured this basebackup to run on my standby server filesystem (which was setup with postgres internal streaming asynchronous replication).

Details as follows:

```
archive_mode = off
max_wal_senders = 5
pg_basebackup -U postgres -D - -Ft -Xf -z  > mycompressed.tar.gz
```

When I unpacked my tar file, the `pg_xlog` directory (which is setup as a physical directory, not a link) is empty, though the backup completion was clean.   I can get the DB to come up, but I get OID not found errors when I select some objects, indicating an inconsistent state.  Am I missing something?

Note:  When I run this procedure on the master, there are no issues at all, and all of the WAL files are captured in the tar file.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Is your pg_xlog directory a symbolic link or mount point or anything other than a bog standard directory?  Are you sure it ended cleanly?  Could you show us the output (to stderr) of the pg_basebackup command, as the well as the output of `tar -tvf mycompressed.tar.gz |tail`

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I've amended the original question to provide more detail.

Comment: I still can't reproduce this with your updated command and using a "cascaded" replica as the source.  Either I get the xlog files I need, or I get an error message saying it can't retrieve them (if it took longer and they are no longer available).  Also, without the pg_xlog you should not be able to bring the cluster up at all, without resorting to something desperate like `pg_resetxlog`.  Are you sure that pg_basebackup is the correct version?

Comment: Yes, I am using there version of pg_basebackup that came with my 9.5 version.  When I unpacked the tar file, there were no files in the pg_xlog directory, so maybe there was failure without it being logged.  Yes, I did in fact use pg_resetxlog since the xlogs were not included in the tar.  So at this point, the question seems to be, why did it not include the xlogs.

Comment: You probably do not need the answer by now but for others - I use pg_basebackup quite often but I always let it create files on its own. So for simple PG installation I get 2 files - base.tar and pg_xlog.tar. Program writes into pg_xlog.tar new WAL logs whole the time during the backup. So I recommend to let pg_basebackup to create files as usual.